# iOS augmented reality with compass and location

Tags: ios, gps, orientation, compass-geolocation, augmented-reality

I'm trying to develop a mini "Around Me" like using camera, compass and location. I would like to display place's images on my screen.
For the moment I have my location and my orientation with compass. I would like to know how can I determine the position of the place I want to display.

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: First I can determine the angle between me and the place I'm looking for ?

Comment: Did you got Ans for this till now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have relative distance and bearing, which you can determine from two points in the same coordinate space using algorithms found on [this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), figuring out where a known coordinate is with respect to a known viewpoint is basically a perspective projection, the math is outlined on [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection). The rotation of the camera is given by the compass, and the tilt by the accelerometer (the position is of course, GPS).

I'm trying to find a better document - there are a couple of extra things to consider - like the camera parameters etc, but this is a good starting point.

If it's too involved (like if you're not comfortable with rotation matrices) we can break it right down to the simple trig.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Thanks to you ! I know concept of rotation matrices but here I not really see how to use it.

Comment: This seems to have the same formulae: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html, I'll update the link in the answer

Answer (score 1):

The code in the [iPhone ARKit project does this](http://www.iphonear.org/), and quite a bit more. While you may not be able to use their complete library, it is a great reference on the subject of augmented reality.

Comment: I would like to understand myself math under this. Tanks for the link but I really would like to implement it myself.

Comment: If you do get that epiphany behind the math, would you be so as to post a write back to this question? I've been trying to grasp it myself for a while

Comment: @RyanR The link mentioned in this thread is not opening up. http://www.iphonear.org

Comment: @Katoch It's a 3.5 year old link, I'm not surprised if the owner of the domain isn't maintaining it anymore. Some quick googling yielded https://github.com/zac/iphonearkit/

Answer (score 0):

Check out 3DAR, it lets you add an AR view to a MKMapView app very easily. There's a video tutorial on this process, as well as some sample code, on the 3DAR site, www.3dar.us

Answer (score 0):

You can create a location based AR app in [Junaio](http://www.junaio.com/develop/docs/documenation/general/location-based/). It's an AR browser. Free to use and deploy in (as long as it's not a custom app and in Junaio).