# direction vector between two geolocations

Tags: vector, geolocation, augmented-reality, haversine, bearing

I'm building an Android AR-App (yes, another one), but I'm more interested in understanding the math behind it than using frameworks (knowing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494069/ios-augmented-reality-with-compass-and-location) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-augment-reality-framework/wiki/HowItWorks)).

Given to locations (lat1,long1) and (lat2,long2) I'm searching for the direction vector (x,y,z) from Location1 to Location2.

Using this [Site](http://www.yourhomenow.com/house/haversine.html) I can calculate the distance and (inital) bearing between Location1 and Location2.

Now I develop two approaches (neglecting altitude)

```
x = distHaversine(lat1,long1,lat1,long2);
z = distHaversine(lat1,long1,lat2,long1);
if (lat1 < lat2)
  z *= -1;
if (long1 > long2)
  x *= -1;
```

and

```
distance = distHaversine(lat1,long1,lat2,long2);
angle = 90.0-bearing(lat1,long1,lat2,long2);
x = cos(angle)*distance;
z = sin(angle)*distance;
```

but now I'm stucked and irritated... shouldnt' the result be the same?
Where do I find my error in reasoning? How do I calcuate the direction vector (or rather: Why didnt work my second approach?)?

Thanks for your help